# Printing branches on a Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

How do you count number of branches, in this case branches with even integers. Here's what I have so far. It seems to work for a couple of the cases.

```
public int evenBranches() {
    return evenBranches(overallRoot);
}

private int evenBranches(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } 
    int val = 0;
    if (root.left != null) {
        val += evenBranches(root.left);
    } else if (root.right != null) {
        val += evenBranches(root.right);
    }
    if (root.data % 2 == 0) {
        return val + 1;
    } else {
        return val;
    } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question title, "Printing branches"? "Counting" surely?

Comment: "It seems to work for a couple of the cases." So which cases, and I assume you've found a case it doesn't work for, which is that?

Comment: Hint: this is a good opportunity to learn about unit testing. And even when you are not using JUnit, it might still be worthwhile for you to consider to write little pieces of test code. You know: like generating dedicated trees with known layout, to then run your code on it and check for the numbers coming back. Start with small examples, and when something goes wrong, you can run that test in a debugger. That is how you resolve such problems systematically. Besides: please check the help center to understand the "missing parts" in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the evenBranches() method as below: I think It will cover all edge cases, If any testcase is left, let me know, I will fix it.

```
    public int evenBranches() {
        return evenBranches(overallRoot, 0);
    }

    private int evenBranches(IntTreeNode root, int count) {
        if(root == null || (root.left == null && root.right == null)) {
            return count;
        }
        if(root.data % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        count += evenBranches(root.left, count);
        count += evenBranches(root.right, count);
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the else condition when checking the occurrences in right branch. Otherwise it will check only one side. eg:

```
private int evenBranches(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } 
    int val = 0;
    if (root.left != null) {
        val += evenBranches(root.left);
    } 

    if (root.right != null) {
        val += evenBranches(root.right);
    }
    if (root.data % 2 == 0) {
        return val + 1;
    } else {
        return val;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well achieve the desired results by using a global variable, and applying BFS (breadth first search) on your tree, in this manner:

```
int evencount = 0; // global-var.
public int evenBranches() {
    evenBranches(overallRoot);
    return evencount;
}
private void evenBranches(IntTreeNode root) {
    if(!root) return;
    if( (root.left || root.right) && (root.data % 2 == 0)){
        evencount++;
    }
    evenBranches(root.left);
    evenBranches(root.right);
}
```